# CSP Whitelisting Not Working in Scratch Org

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, scratch-org, content-security-policy

I'm adding Google's [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) element to a Lightning component. Following [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display), I added this JS snippet to the community in my scratch org:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer>
```

After saving that change, the CSP warning indicated it was being blocked and that I should whitelist third-party API's. I added https://www.google.com to the Trust Sites list in my scratch org, however, the CSP warning continue to pop-up indicating it was being blocked. How can I get my scratch org's CSP to correctly whitelist this URL so I can use reCAPTCHA?

Comment: in what context? LEX, lighting communities?

Comment: and when you say not working, is it right after deploying? or even after adding it and activating it?

Comment: I've added that script snippet to my community <head>. Even after whitelisting google.com I'm still getting the CSP warning saying the script is being blocked.

Comment: did you push the cspTrustedsites metadata after  creating the scatch org?

Comment: and is it `Active` ?

Comment: I didn't push cspTrustedSites metadata. I wasn't aware of that until you just mentioned it. But wouldn't manually adding it to Trusted Sites in the scratch org do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, however, you have to make sure it is active, also check remote site settings

Comment: Looking at my list of Trusted Sites in my scratch org, all whitelisted URLs are active. You mentioned Remote Site Settings; should google.com be added there as well?

Comment: might as well give it a shot